# Yii2 advanced with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new to Yii2.

I want to use MongoDB with Yii2-advanced. For that, I have found this library:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb

The issue is it doesn't explain much about the installation and configurations.

As the read me says I have added following into the `common\config\main-local.php` file:

```
'mongodb' => [
  'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
 ],
```

But what should I do with the default **db** key which is there for of the MySQL connection:

```
'db' => [
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2_advanced_mongo',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

If I comment out that db key and try to login, then it gives me following error:

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> Unknown component ID: db

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add  the entry properly,  if you want use the entry `db` for accessing your db datas you should comment the db entry related to mysql  and assign db to your mongodb entry

```
'db' => [
  'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'mongodb://your_user_name:your_password@localhost:27017/your_database',
],

//'db' => [
//   'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
//   'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2_advanced_mongo',
//   'username' => 'root',
//   'password' => 'root',
//   'charset' => 'utf8',
//],
```

Comment: I tried that too. It gives Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException

Calling unknown method: yii\mongodb\QueryBuilder::build()

Comment: 1 ) have you installe the mongo db components properly .. ?  2 ) hare you sure that the queryBuilder work correcly with mongoDB ?  looking to  Yii2 doc i don't see any  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-querybuilder.html  ...build() function ..  .. and PS : this mean that mongodb  access work

Comment: Yes installed MongoDB components correctly. No, I'm not as I'm totally new to this and readme doesn't explains much.

Comment: .. all what we have is the doc..  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-querybuilder.html  ... you can use the function you have in the doc ..